# JQuery Datatables CSV, PDF exporter with Font Awesome

Tags: javascript, datatables

https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html

Is there a way to have the export for CSV and PDF utilize the alt tag value vs ignoring the font awesome value?  for example:`<i class='fa fa-handshake-o' alt='Y'></i>`.

Currently CSV and PDF exports ignore the font-awesome icons and leave the columns empty, if it could simply read the alt tag data that would be great.

I did find a sort solution that uses the alt tag but have not located a CSV or PDF export option.